# How to remove both game objects in an array if they collide?

Tags: javascript, html, game-physics

I'm creating a game that randomly spawns meteors and i want to destroy meteors that collides each other. I keep my meteors in an array and when i want to spawn a  meteor i push Meteor class to that array. I have my 2D collision algorithm but i cannot figure out the logic of how to select which meteor to destroy. Here is my meteor class related code. Thank you.

```
const meteorCollision = (a, aIndex, b, bIndex) => {
    if (a !== undefined && b !== undefined) {
        if (a.x < b.x + 50 &&
            a.x + 50 > b.x &&
            a.y < b.y + 50 &&
            a.y + 50 > b.y) {
            meteors.splice(aIndex, 1);
            meteors.splice(bIndex, 1);
        }
    }

}
```

```
meteorCollision(meteor, meteorIndex, meteors[meteorIndex + 1], meteorIndex + 1);
```

```
const spawnMeteorP = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        let x, y;
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            x = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -50 : cvs.width + 50;
            y = Math.random() * cvs.height;
        } else {
            x = Math.random() * cvs.width;
            y = Math.random() < .5 ? -50 : cvs.height + 50
        }





        const angle = Math.atan2(rocketY - y, rocketX - x);
        const velocity = {
            x: Math.cos(angle),
            y: Math.sin(angle)

        }


        meteors.push(new MeteorP(x, y, velocity))
    }, 1500)
}
```

Comment: You mean `meteors.splice(aIndex, 1)` isn't working?

Comment: I want to check any collisions between meteors. My algorthm just removes if meteors in-order in array.

Answer (score 0):

I got it by adding another forEach to map all items in array. Not sure if it is the most efficient solution but that's what i came up with.

```
const meteorCollision = (a, aIndex,) => {
    meteors.forEach((b, bIndex) => {
        if (a !== undefined && b !== undefined && a !== b) {
            if (a.x < b.x + 50 &&
                a.x + 50 > b.x &&
                a.y < b.y + 50 &&
                a.y + 50 > b.y) {
                meteors.splice(aIndex, 1);
                meteors.splice(bIndex, 1);
                meteorexp.play();
            }
        }
    })


}
```

```
meteorCollision(meteor, meteorIndex);
```